# F# formatting string with list slices

Tags: list, f#, transformation

I have a list that represents a label and a series of data values like this: (with many more elements)

`[10; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1]`

And I want to write it to a file like this:

`|y 10 |x 0 0 1 0 0 1`

What is the easiest way to accomplish this formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to separate the first element of the list:

```
let input = [10; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1]
match input with
| label::data ->
    let body = data |> List.map string |> String.concat " "
    printf "|y %d |x %s" label body
| _ -> 
    failwith "Label is missing!"
```

If you want to write the data to a file, you can use `sprintf` (which returns a string) rather than `printf`. If your data was very big, it is better to write the numbers one by one, rather than concatenating one big string in memory, but the idea would be the same.

Comment: I think your second `printf` arg should be `body`, not `data`.

Comment: Nice! I have to get used to try more pattern matching.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks! Fixed.